# Mapping RGB/hex color codes to general color categories

Tags: colors, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, rgb

Is there a dataset that maps each of the ~16M RGB or hex color values to a general color family/category - e.g. red, purple, orange, beige, brown, etc. - that I could access programmatically or load into a database or JSON document to cross-refence the color codes against? The use case is to classify the results of PIL color detection of swatch files into a small set of color pickers for a shopping site. It would also work if the mapping is a bit more granular, say 100-200 categories, since it would be easy enough to map those to my target 10-15 myself. I have some knowledge of kNN classification and will work with that if I have to, but it would be so much easier to use a static mapping if one already exists.

Comment: See [xkcd Color Survey Results](http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/) for some insights on color names.

Comment: That's an excellent resource, thank you! And I love that they have color names such as "booger" and "baby puke green". :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a table such as the one in X11

http://www.astrouw.edu.pl/~jskowron/colors-x11/rgb.html

In order to find color proximity, it's best to transform the colors to Lab color space first, so that euclidean distances have more meaning, and then nearest neighbor would give good results.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please tell me how to transform colors to Lab? The PIL getcolors() method is giving me the RGB values in tuples - if I converted the X11 color values to RGB, couldn't I just calculate the Euclidean distance between two RGB tuples without converting to any other format? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The RGB space does not accurately represent human perception of color similarity.  This is why CIE Lab was developed.  There are various ways to transform, but it's not trivial to implement yourself.  If you can use a library as mentioned in Ajay's answer, go for it.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert from RGB to CIE Lab color space wherein Euclidian distance between two color selections is perceptually more meaningful. Here is the link to all relevant color space transformation formulae used in OpenCV's color conversion method (cvtColor): http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html

Since your use case is to compare two swatches, I would advise you to use texture descriptors (http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/texclass/with.html) in addition to color information for better results.